# Error when i try to enter a password: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'apply') throws at exp....aura_prod.js:13:40835

Tags: lightning-web-components, experience-cloud

HTML

```
<template>

  <lightning-card class="slds-var-p-around_medium">
    <div class="slds-grid slds-grid_vertical">

      <!--Logo/baranding-->
      <div class="slds-col">
        <p class="fontSizeCustom">Sign in </p>
      </div>

      <!--Input Types-->
      <div class="slds-col">
        <lightning-input type="text" variant="standard" name="name" label="Username" placeholder="Enter Username"
          onchange={handleUsername} value={email}></lightning-input>
      </div>
      <div class="slds-col">
        <lightning-input type="password" variant="standard" name="name" label="Password" placeholder="Enter Password"
          onchange={handlePassword} value={password}></lightning-input>
      </div>

      <!--Login Button-->
      <div class="slds-col">
        <div class="button" onclick={handleLogin}>Log In</div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </lightning-card>

</template>
```

JS

```
import Email from '@salesforce/schema/Contact.Email';
import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';

export default class NitronsolarLogin extends LightningElement {

  email;
  password;
  
  handleUsername(event){
    this.email=event.target.value;
  }
  
  handlepassword(event){
    this.password=event.target.value;
  }
  
  handleLogin(){
    console.log("Inside Login");
    console.log("Email Value: ", this.email);
    console.log('Password Value: ', this.password);
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Can you share a screenshot of the exact error and stack trace ..from the browser

Comment: I have tried to upload the image. Does it makethe question clearer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaScript is cAsE-sEnSiTiVe. You must pay close attention when writing your code. In this case, the error comes from `onchange={handlePassword}` in your template and `handlepassword(event){` in your controller. Change one or the other so that they match the exact same case, either `handlePassword` or `handlepassword`. They should match exactly.

Comment: Thanks a million, code works perfectly now. This is new, there ares cases where apex is case sensitive. I belive this comes with experience and training.

Comment: @OgunseyinMagnus JavaScript isn't Apex. They're two different languages. JavaScript is case-sensitive, Apex is not (generally) case sensitive, unless it's interacting with case-sensitive technology, like SOAP or JavaScript.

Comment: Generally you should keep cases consistent anyway. It makes your code easier to read and avoids bugs.